# How to disable south debug logging in django?

Tags: django, debugging, testing, django-south

When I run my tests in Django, after a fail I got several pages of debug output from South, like these:

```
south: DEBUG: south execute "CREATE INDEX "sometable_4d5bad5" ON "video_playable" ("network_id");" with params "[]"
south: DEBUG: south execute "CREATE INDEX "sometable_790e6d98" ON "video_playable" ("published");" with params "[]"
south: DEBUG: south execute "CREATE INDEX "sometable_72312277" ON "video_playable" ("archived");" with params "[]"
```

And with all this logging output, the relevant error messages are lost in a sea of garbage. Is there a way to disable this ouput?

Comment: This is a really helpful post - http://pypede.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/disable-south-debug-logging-when-testing-apps-with-nose-in-django/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put this somewhere in your code. I have it in `myapp/migrations/__init__.py`

```
import logging
south_logger=logging.getLogger('south')
south_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can set [SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/settings.html#south-tests-migrate) to `False` in your `setting.py`. This will disable all migrations during the tests. I know it's not exactly what you want, but hope will be usefull

> If this is False, South’s test runner integration will make the test
>   database be created using syncdb, rather than via migrations (the
>   default). Set this to False if you have migrations which take too long
>   to migrate every time tests run, but be wary if you rely on migrations
>   to do special things.

Comment: yes, this does not exactly solve my problem, because currently my tests depend on data migrations. but these messages are so annoying that redesigning the tests are worth the trouble... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
import logging
import south.logger
logging.getLogger('south').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

I am able to set this in my setting/testing.py

Also if this is only bothering you with your django-nose tests add

```
nosetests --nologcapture
```