# How do I disable django migration debug logging?

Tags: python, django, nose, django-migrations, django-nose

Very similar to [lafagundes question about south migration debug logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578223/how-to-disable-south-debug-logging-in-django), except I'm not using south - I'm using plain Django 1.7 migrations. I'm also using [django-nose](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose/) test runner.

When I run `manage.py test`, there is no debug logging output captured:

```
(codesy)lcrouch:codesy lcrouch$ ./manage.py test
nosetests --verbosity=1
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
......E...............................
======================================================================
ERROR: test_return_state (auctions.tests.utils_tests.IssueStateTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I run an individual test module, e.g., `./manage.py test auctions.tests.utils_tests`, the debug logging output includes all of the `django.db.backends.schema: DEBUG` lines involved in the Django migrations:

```
(codesy)lcrouch:codesy lcrouch$ ./manage.py test auctions.tests.utils_tests
nosetests auctions.tests.utils_tests --verbosity=1
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_return_state (auctions.tests.utils_tests.IssueStateTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lcrouch/code/codesy/codesy/auctions/tests/utils_tests.py", line 13, in test_return_state
    fake_gh_client = fudge.Fake(github_client).returns_fake().provides('get_repo').returns_fake().provides('get_issue').returns_fake().has_attr(state='open')
  File "/Users/lcrouch/python/codesy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fudge/__init__.py", line 1133, in returns_fake
    exp = self._get_current_call()
  File "/Users/lcrouch/python/codesy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fudge/__init__.py", line 765, in _get_current_call
    "Call to a method that expects a predefined call but no such call exists.  "
FakeDeclarationError: Call to a method that expects a predefined call but no such call exists.  Maybe you forgot expects('method') or provides('method') ?
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
django.db.backends.schema: DEBUG: CREATE TABLE "django_migrations" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "app" varchar(255) NOT NULL, "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL, "applied" datetime NOT NULL); (params [])
django.db.backends.schema: DEBUG: CREATE TABLE "django_content_type" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "app_label" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "model" varchar(100) NOT NULL); (params [])
django.db.backends.schema: DEBUG: CREATE TABLE "django_content_type__new" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "app_label" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "model" varchar(100) NOT NULL, UNIQUE ("app_label", "model")); (params [])
...
django.db.backends.schema: DEBUG: DROP TABLE "socialaccount_socialapp"; (params [])
django.db.backends.schema: DEBUG: ALTER TABLE "socialaccount_socialapp__new" RENAME TO "socialaccount_socialapp"; (params [])
```

Which makes it really hard to get back up to the actual failure.

How can I disable this output? Either at the django or nose level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind disabling migrations in testing, you can do so by adding the following to your settings.py:

```
TESTING = 'test' in sys.argv

if TESTING:
    class DisableMigrations(object):
        def __contains__(self, item):
            return True

        def __getitem__(self, item):
            return "notmigrations"

    MIGRATION_MODULES = DisableMigrations()
```

This will just create the database in one go, rather than stepping through each migration.

If you want to keep migrations running in tests, you might be able to remove the messages by updating the logging setting.

```
TESTING = 'test' in sys.argv

if TESTING:
    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'handlers': {
            'file': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
                'filename': '/tmp/codesy-debug.log',
            },
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django.db.backends.schema': {
                'handlers': ['file'],
                'propagate': True,
                'level': 'INFO',
            },
            '': {
                'handlers': ['file'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, the LOGGING configuration approach is nicer. But it seems like this should be an option in django itself?

Comment: I also ended up tweaking the `LOGGING` settings, specifically I just set `handlers` to `['console']` and `level` to `'WARNING'`.

Comment: Django 2.0, first example: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notmigrations'`

Answer (score 2):

To quickly remove the logging messages, you can run with:

`./manage.py test --nologcapture`

The messages are being captured by the [nose logcapture plugin](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/logcapture.html), which has additional options for fine tuning.  However, django-nose has an [old issue](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose/issues/7) that may prevent you from using many of those from the command line.  It's scheduled for [milestone v1.4.2](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose/milestones/v1.4.2), but that's a month overdue.  You may be able to work around those with `.noserc` or `nose.cfg` file - see [nose docs](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) for format.

Comment: That works quickly, but I **want** to capture the other logging output. I just don't want the `DEBUG` level output.